# Update the related posts before deleting the category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, pdo

I have 2 tables with `one-to-many` relation:

```
                     posts table
___________________________________________________
| id | title | content | category_id | posts_order |                                        
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|
| 1  | test1 | testing |     1       |       0     |   
| 2  | test2 | testing |     1       |       1     |   
| 3  | test3 | testing |     2       |       2     |   
| .  | ..... | ....... |     .       |       .     |   
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|


       categories table
___________________________
| c_id | c_name | c_order |                                       
|______|________|_________|
|   1  |  cat1  |    0    |      
|   2  |  cat2  |    1    |      
|   3  |  cat3  |    2    |      
| .    | ..... | .......  |      
|______|_______|__________|
```

They are joined through the `posts.category_id` and `categories.c_id`, On delete & update `CASCADE`.

What I'm seeking for is, Before deleting the category, Update the `category_id` to `100` which is the uncategorized category.

I tried:

```
global $wpdb;

//Category id to remove.
$remove_id = 2;

//Column to update
$data = array(
    "category_id" => 100
);

$where = array('category_id' => $remove_id);

//Update the posts that has the id 2
$wpdb->update('posts', $data, $where);

//Delete the category
$wpdb->delete( 'categories', array( 'c_id' => $remove_id ) );
```

But I get that error:

```
WordPress database error: [Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 

(`myposts`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES 

`categories` (`c_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)]
UPDATE `posts` SET `category_id` = '100' WHERE `category_id` = '2'
```

What to do to update the posts with `category_id` = `2` to `100`, Before deleting the category with `c_id` = `2`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because of the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is locking the `Foreign Keys` in your `child-table`. In this case, your `child-table` is `posts`.

The purpose of `ON UPDATE CASCADE` would be to update the `category_id` field in `posts` if it changed in `categories` (the `parent-table`).

For instance, changing `c_id` on the `categories` table form `1` to `001` would alter all the `category_id` fields on `posts` to match that change (assuming that the data types allowed for this change).

If this is the functionality you want to keep, then you need to perform your `update` statement on the `parent-table`, not the `child`.

So instead of updating `posts`, you need to perform this `update` on `categories` and then it will `cascade` down to `posts` for the relevant `category_id`s

---

Ahh, so looking at your use of `CASCADE`, I don't think what you want can happen in the current design. You will be unable to `update` the `category_id` of `posts` due to the `on update cascade`, and if you attempt to `update` table `categories` setting `c_id = 100 where c_id = 2` and then deleting `c_id = 100`, you will delete all the `posts` with `category_id = 100` as well.

I would recommend removing that `on update cascade` constraint from your table if you want to keep the `posts` from `deleted` categories.

Additionally, using the `category_id` column as an indication of belonging to a `deleted` category is bad practice. What if you wanted to know what a post's former category was?

It is also generally bad to alter `id` columns in this way because it means that they cannot be indexed as easily. Consider changing the database design to move `deleted` categories to some sort of history table. You can then search records on `posts` as normal and simply included the `deleted` categories as you need to.

Comment: I can edit the on update part, Because currently the `c_id` won't be changed

Comment: So you suggest creating a new table and move these posts to it?

Comment: You could move the `posts` to a different table, but that may be unnecessary. Instead, I would move the deleted `category_id`s to a different table. Then you can leave the records on `posts` as they are. To know whether a post's category is deleted, you simply check to see if that `category_id` is in the new `deleted_categories` table. Since doing this would change the database design, you may have to update your old queries searching the `posts` table. You could also add a field to the `categories` table like `is_deleted` 1=yes, 0=no and then key off of that. Anything that preserves the id.

Comment: I edited on update and on delete to `no action`, But I still get the same error, What should the action be?

Comment: Setting the `constraint` to `no action` will produce the same error if you try and `delete` or `update` the `posts` table. This is because they are following the same rules as the `on cascade` option. You want to remove the `constraint` from the table entirely. Run this: `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;` to see what the constraints are called.

Comment: I think it's called `posts_categories` it's in the error `(`myposts`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)`, Or that's something else?

Comment: No, I believe you are correct. That is the correct `constraint`. Remove it an you will be able to implement your original intention. However, if you do so, then you will lose the ability to recover a `posts` old `category_id`. Think carefully whether there is any situation where you would need that information again. If you do need to keep that information, then follow one of my previous suggestions to retain it in your database model, `or` ask your database administrator/ solution architect if they have any ideas.

Comment: I believe you should be able to make a new `foreign key constraint` on the appropriate columns, remove the old on that contains the `cascade`, and finally rename the newly created `constraint` something more appropriate.

Comment: And what should I set the on delete and update for the new one?

Comment: Thanks for your  time and your help, I discovered that the problem was with the `c_id`